# NSString to Float = 0 instead of value

Tags: objective-c

I'm bit lost, I tried to convert NSString from an Array, But, by using floatValue, I'm getting 0 instead of a value. (Even if extracted String values are correct). I'm doing something wrong, but, I don't understand. Here is the code.

```
NSString *sRatioMin;
NSString *sRatioMax;
float fRatioMin;
float fRatioMax;
int incrementation;

for(incrementation = 0; incrementation < [myObjet count]; incrementation = incrementation+3)
{
    sRatioMin  = [myObjet objectAtIndex:incrementation+1]; --> I'm getting good value
    sRatioMax  = [myObjet objectAtIndex:incrementation+2];--> I'm getting good value

    // ici Valeur Min & Max à comparer avec le ratio
    fRatioMin = [sRatioMin floatValue]; --> 0 ?! 
    fRatioMax = [sRatioMax floatValue]; --> 0 ?!
NSLog(@"mystring = %.1f ",[sRatioMin floatValue]); // --> Result still 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's inside the strings that you are trying to convert.Probably they don't store real values, but strings like @"Hello".
For now I can tell you that you are risking to go out of bounds, so correct it:

```
for(incrementation = 0; incrementation < [myObjet count]-3; incrementation = incrementation+3) {...}
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot! I just checked array and, values are stored with ',' instead of '.'